# I'm pretty sure I'm suppose this statement

Tags: javascript

OK, I'm kinda stuck on this one. I'm looking in my book.

I'm thinking I'm supposed to use the if or the else statement with this. When I try to validate it is coming up with 3 errors. Can someone point out hints to what I'm missing?

Thank you. I'm not this far in javascript yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWERS
function checkGrade(grade) {
switch(grade) {

    case "A":
        document.write("Your grade is excellent.");
        break;
    case "B":
        document.write("Your grade is good.");
        break;
    case "C":
        document.write("Your grade is fair.");
        break;
    case"D":
        document.write("You are barely passing.");
        break;
    case"F":
        document.write("you failed.");
        break;
    defult:
        document.write("You did not enter a valid letter grade.")
        break;

    }
    }
//STOP HIDING INCOMPATIBLE BROWERS-->
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body
<form name ="gradeForm" "action" ="">
<input type="text" name="grade" />
<input type="button" value="CheckGrade" onclick="checkGrade(document.gradeForm.grade.value);" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are y'all seeing anything? I see an opening paragraph and then "// //]]>". I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @Closure: he edited the question, cache maybe?

Comment: @jcoc611 My page loaded before the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the second > on your body tag, and you have an extra quote before your form's action attribute.

You may also want to put ".toUpperCase()" in this statement so the user can enter "a" or "A".

```
switch(grade.toUpperCase()) {
```

With @Matchu's noted fix of "default", I was able to run your code in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome.

Final version can be seen in [this pastie](http://jsbin.com/ocavu3).

Comment: Ok thank you.. Can someone explain to me what the vote thing is about?

Comment: @sha: in addition to the votes system, be sure to click the check mark next to an answer if it took care of your issue. This lets others know that the question is answered, gives the answerer credit for being right, and gives you credit for remembering to accept answers on your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider deleting the extra set of `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<HTML>` and `<HEAD>` tags. I'm not sure if they're the source of your js errors (you didn't tell us what the errors were) but they certainly aren't helping.

You are missing spaces on `case"F"` and `case"D"`. They should be `case "F" and`case "D"`. This isn't an error per se, but best to keep it consistent.

Your `<body>` tag is also left unclosed. This is probably the source of your errors.

Edit:

Some more stuff:

`<form name ="gradeForm" "action" ="">` should be `<form name="gradeForm" action="">`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<input type="text" name="grade" />` to `<input type="text" id="grade" />`

Use name= if you are submitting a form, but id= if you need javascript to id it.  It is possible to have several inputs with the same name.

--Dave

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, except for some typos. Note the `defult` instead of `default`, for instance, and the unclosed `<body` start tag.

What do you mean, exactly, when you refer to errors? Are these errors in the Javascript console, or errors running the HTML through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/)? The W3's HTML validator doesn't check Javascript syntax.

Comment: @Dawson: my tests agree :) Edited out. I'm still not a fan of the inconsistency in style, though :/

Comment: The errors i am getting is 1.Line 40, Column 25: an attribute specification must start with a name or name token 2.Line 40, Column 26: character data is not allowed here.3.Line 41, Column 34: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag